# My function doesn't post in the database

Tags: php

So I tried coding a function that allows the user to post a mood, chosen by a slider. I succeeded in connecting the color with an ID, then I tried making a post function. However Nothing happens.

this is where i call the functions.

```
if (isset($_POST['ready'])) {
    $mood = new Post();
    $moodColor = $_POST['mood'];
    $statementMood = $mood->getMood($moodColor); //connects the color with an ID

    while ($row = $statementMood->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $moodID = $row['moodID'];

    }
    $moodID = $_GET['moodID'];
    $userID = $currentUser['userID'];
    $statementPost = $mood->postMood(); //put the emotion in the database.
//header('location: home.php');
}
```

these are the two functions.

```
 public function getMood($moodColor){
    $conn = db::getInstance();

    $statementMood = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM moods WHERE color = :cMood");
    $statementMood->bindParam(":cMood", $moodColor);
    $statementMood->execute();
    return $statementMood;
}

public function postMood(){
    $conn = db::getInstance();

    $statementPost = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO postsmoodi (userID, moodID) VALUES (:userID, :moodID)");
    $statementPost ->bindValue(':userID', $this->userID);
    $statementPost->bindValue(':moodID', $this->moodID);
    return $statementPost->execute();
}
```

this is the form where the button to post is.

```
<form class="input" action="mood.php" method="get">
    <input id="hiddenValue" type="hidden" class="data" name="mood" value="">
    <button class="moodReady" type="submit" name="ready">Ready</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use <input type="submit" name="ready"> instead of <button> tag

Comment: Your button is a submit with some value, change button to input and put a value there.

Comment: the button has `type` set `submit`, the form uses get and OP is accessing the data using `$_POST`.

Comment: their button's fine ^ it's the method's that's wrong in the first bit of their code

Comment: where's this coming from? `$_GET['moodID']`

Comment: Your code at the top makes very little sense. First you set `$moodID` from the database query, then you immediately overwrite it from `$_GET['moodID']`. What's the point of doing the query first? And your `while` loop keeps overwriting the same variable, so it will just set it from the last row returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) instead of `$_POST`, as your form uses `method="get"`

```
if (isset($_GET['ready'])) {
    $mood = new Post();
    $moodColor = $_POST['mood'];
    $statementMood = $mood->getMood($moodColor); //connects the color with an ID

    while ($row = $statementMood->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $moodID = $row['moodID'];

    }
    $moodID = $_GET['moodID'];
    $userID = $currentUser['userID'];
    $statementPost = $mood->postMood(); //put the emotion in the database.
//header('location: home.php');
}
```

Comment: when I use your code, it says: `Notice: Undefined index: mood in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype2\mood.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: moodID in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototype2\mood.php on line 43
`

Comment: because you don't have `moodID` in your form